# Is there a parameter I can set to dynamically limit or increase the amount of posts per page

Tags: wordpress

Let's say I have a Wordpress blog that by default shows 10 posts per page but sometimes I'd like to show 50 posts per page. Is there a parameter in the URL that I can add to increase that limit to 50?

**Update**
This appears to work and is used in header.php:

```
// Support posts per page - Note: needs review
if (isset($_REQUEST['posts_per_page'])) {
    $pageCount = $_REQUEST['posts_per_page'];
    $wp_query->set("posts_per_page", $pageCount);
    $wp_query->get_posts();
}
```

Comment: this probably belongs on http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @meklarian http://wordpress.stackexchange.com is dedicated to WordPress questions.

Comment: +1 @toscho Aha, didn't know that existed.

Comment: @toscho - ditto. should future wordpress questions be asked there? there's a wordpress keyword here.

Comment: Yes, they should. You get more and better answers there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, [WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) has a parameter [`posts_per_page`](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=posts_per_page). You can change it by filtering `pre_get_posts` or by using your own query.

Here is an [example from WordPress.Answers](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/17473/adding-pagination-on-a-custom-author-page).

Comment: awesome. thank you! :) it seems it's not supported by default? meaning i had to add the code from the examples to get it to work. once it was working it seemed to ignore other request variables. so after looking at the code in wp_query i wrote it as shown above to make it work with other request variables. i could be doing this wrong.

Comment: @1.21 gigawatts I made an update to my answer and added a link to a nice sample code. Use a filter, and [check your incoming data](http://codex.wordpress.org/Data_Validation) before you send it to the data base. ;)